# find in a shell script gives an unknown predicate `-v' error

Tags: bash

find in a shell script gives an unknown predicate `-v' error

Output:

```
/bin/find /home/dev/public_html/ | grep -v "^secure" | grep -v "^folder1/folder2"
/bin/find: unknown predicate `-v'
```

Code:

```
FINDP="  | grep -v \"^secure\" | grep -v \"^folder1/folder2\""
echo "/bin/find /home/dev/public_html/$FINDP";
`/bin/find /home/dev/public_html/$FINDP`
```

Any ideas how to fix this? (The idea is to store the results from the backticks in a variable later.)

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) !! That is: don't use this approach since it is fragile.

Comment: As a side note: you have been asking [a lot of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4241116/sam-roberts?tab=questions) and still miss how to format and not accepting any. May be good to check [ask].

Answer (score 2):

You can't store complex commands in strings. It doesn't work. This is [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Specifically in your case the shell doesn't see `|` as a shell pipeline but instead as a regular character and so `find` sees the `-v` argument to `grep` and complains.

Comment: Don't use a string for complex commands. It *cannot* work reliably. (Some people will tell you to use `eval` for this sort of thing. Don't listen to them. It works in some cases but is very fragile and dangerous.)